# Test-Path in PowerShell behaving weirdly. Same snippet in different scripts returning different values

Tags: powershell, iis

I have a couple of scripts where we retrieve IIS and Certificates related data from multiple servers. The servers list is stored in a text file and since we have multiple servers, we are using a multi threading script to parallelize the runs. Now we use the below code to invoke the multi threading script

```
function Get-ScriptDirectory
{
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

$PowerShellPath = Get-ScriptDirectory
$MultiThreadPowerShellPath = $PowerShellPath + "\MultiThreading_Invoke.ps1"

If(Test-Path $MultiThreadPowerShellPath)
{
    ."$MultiThreadPowerShellPath"
}
else
{
    throw "PowerShell Multi Threading File not found at $MultiThreadPowerShellPath"
}
```

Same snippet is used in both the files. But the IIS Script is able to find the file and use it but the certificates file is not. It throws me an error that Multi threading file is not found at the location How can this happen? Both the certificate script and IIS script reside in the same folder as the multithreading one.

Comment: Assuming you verified that the `$MultiThreadPowerShellPath` that gets thrown is the correct one, the only other option I can think of is credentials. You could run Procmon, start the run and look for access denied messages.

Comment: Maybe the path contains `[` or `]`? Always use `-LiteralPath`.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I am running both the scripts from the same ISE window. That rules out access related problems, doesn't it ?

Comment: @wOxxOm The path doesn't contain any braces. It is a simple UNC share path

Comment: One possible explanation is that Get-ScriptDirectory will return $null if not executed from a script.   If you are running from the ISE, this might happen if one of the scripts hasn't been saved yet.

Comment: @Burt_Harris both  the scripts were saved before running and I even had them run from a WPF app. One of them ran and the other one didn't

Comment: So what's the exact error message you are getting?   I mean the exact message, what does it say after "PowerShell Multi Threading File not found at "

Comment: It is unable to find that multi threading script

Comment: I find it difficult to find the relevant and irrelevant parts in your question. The fact that multithreading is involved is irrelevant?! You can try setting PSDebug to Trace with `Set-PSDebug -Trace 2`. You can add verbose flags. You can still use procmon and *verify* instead of trying to *reason* about it. You can post the exact error message as asked. You can post the exact path giving problems. What you can not expect from us is mindreading. I'm pretty sure a procmon session would at least provide you some good clue as to what the problem is.